# Find a sequence of functions that converge weakly to 1/2

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence

I'm trying solve the following problem:

> Find an example of a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $$(f_n)_\#\mathscr{L} = \mathscr L$$ but $f_n\rightharpoonup 1/2$ (weak convergence). Note that $(f_n)_\#(\mathscr L)$ denotes the push-forward image measure, i.e. $(f_n)_\#\mathscr L = \mathscr L(f_n^{-1})$ and $\mathscr L$ is the Lebesgue measure (restricted to $[0,1]$).

Unfortunately, the problem doesn't have any more details other than this. My professor helped me figure out to consider the sequence
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}2^{n-1}\left(x - \frac{j}{2^{n-1}}\right)\chi_{[j/2^{n-1},(j+1)/2^{n-1})} \qquad \text{and}\qquad f_n(1) = 1.
$$

and I've proved the equivalence of the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure and the Lebesgue measure, but I'm having a lot of trouble proving the weak convergence to 1/2.

My professor just said to prove that if $f\in C([0,1])$, then I need to show that $$\left< f_n,f\right> \to \left<1/2,f\right>$$
where $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ is the $L^2$ inner product.

Some immediate concerns I had were why would we assume that this is the weak convergence we want to use and also why do we assume $f$ is continuous. It seems the problem statement is missing details about the setting we are in.

My other issue is that I'm just stuck on how to prove this limit. My work so far consists of

$$\begin{align*}
        \left|\left< \frac{1}{2}-f_n,f\right> \right| &= \left|\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2}-f_n(x)\right) f(x)dx\right|\\
        &= \left|\int_0^1f(x) \left(\sum_{j=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-2^{n-1}\left( x- \frac{j}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)\right)\chi_{\left[\frac{j}{2^{n-1}},\frac{j+1}{2^{n-1}}\right)}dx\right|\\
       &=   \left|\int_0^1f(x) \sum_{j=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}- 2^{n-1}x + j\right)\chi_{\left[\frac{j}{2^{n-1}},\frac{j+1}{2^{n-1}}\right)} dx\right|\\
       &= \left| \sum_{j=0}^{2^{n-1}-1} \int_{\frac{j}{2^{n-1}}}^{\frac{j+1}{2^{n-1}}}f(x) \left(\frac{1}{2}- 2^{n-1}x + j\right) dx\right|\\
       &= \left|\sum_{j=0}^{2^{n-1}-1} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} f\left(\frac{j+1}{2^{n-1}}-x\right) \left(2^{n-1}x-\frac{1}{2}\right) dx\right| \tag{by substitution}
    \end{align*}$$

I've tried bringing the absolute values in and pulling out the sup of $f$, but it feels like all the things I've tried don't actually make the total quantity small, which makes me doubt that my original sequence was correct or perhaps this norm isn't correct, but if that's the case, I'm not sure what to do.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'll greatly appreciate it.